# Excel VBA - How to Exit Code if Sheet Not Found

Tags: vba, excel

My code is to merge multiple sheet from a folder. I achieved the first requirement which merge all the sheet1 of target workbooks. But now, i want to merge the 4th sheet of the target workbooks. before that i need to check whether the sheet is exist or not. if exist the code should merge the 4th sheets. This one also i managed to achieved. However if the the 4th sheet not exist the code should do nothing. This part im still stuck. below are the code.

```
Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MS2")
Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
    If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "PID2" Then
        Wkb.Sheets(4).Activate
        Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(4).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
        CopyRng.Copy Dest
        Wkb.Close False
        "ElseIf Worksheets(i).Name <> "PID2" Then"
        "Wkb.Close False"
        "Exit Sub"
        End If
        Next i
    End If

    Filename = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: The elseif part shouldn't be within quotes, just else will do and no need of Exit Sub within that else part, the loop will take care of checking the next file.

Comment: is the 4th sheet named "PID2"? in that case the line `Wkb.Sheets(4).Activate` should change to `Worksheets(i).Activate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PID2 is the 4th sheet you want to copy, if it exists

```
Sub t()
    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MS2")
    Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename)

            For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                If Worksheets(i).Name = "PID2" Then
                    Worksheets(i).Activate
                    Set CopyRng = Worksheets(i).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                    Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
                    CopyRng.Copy Dest
                End If
            Next i

            Wkb.Close False
        End If

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You should also add `Worksheets(I)` before the `Cells()` usage to be safe in `Set CopyRng...` also you're using the active sheet to determine the number of cells. Should that also be the `Worksheet(I)`?

Comment: Yes. But i didn't want to change much of the original code. That is why I also left the `.Activate` part.

Answer (score 1):

PFA for the required code, I have made some modification in the code.

```
    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MS2")

Filename = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until Filename = vbNullString

    If Not Filename = ThisWB Then

        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename)

        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

            If Worksheets(i).Name = "PID2" Then

                Wkb.Sheets(i).Activate
                Set CopyRng = Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
                Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
                CopyRng.Copy Dest

                Exit For

            End If
        Next i

        Wkb.Close False

    End If

    Filename = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify some criteria and then exit after that,

ie,

```
If something = <criteria> Then
   goto exitsub
end if

exitsub:
```

This will jump to `exitsub` using the `:` at the end of the string you specify `exitsub:` You could make it anything you wanted, eg `goToEndOfSub:`

```
If something = <criteria> Then
      goto goToEndOfSub
end if

goToEndOfSub:
```

Also you can use the [Exit Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx), in your case a do loop.

```
Exit Do
```

Comment: Seems needlessly elaborated - you could just put "Exit Sub" where relevent.

Comment: @Francky_V, maybe, but better to thoroughly explain for someone else who might stumble upon this question in the future.